# Linux Mint installer can't properly detect partitions

Tags: partitioning, installation, ssd, linux-mint, gparted

I bought a new SSD HD and I successfully installed Windows 10; now I'd like to install Linux Mint with a bootable USB key.

During the Mint installation, when I attempt to create the partition here's what [I saw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o6fd.png).

I opened GParted and I tried to manually create partitions on `/dev/sda`in order to prepare the installation of Mint, when I try to format the partition in ext4, GParted returns this error:

```
~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -L "" /dev/sda5
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/sda5 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

So, I ran `sudo fdisk -l` after GParted error and this is the result:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1647394816 bytes, 3217568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0e03fec0

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   1026047   1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1026048 417662975 416636928 198.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       417665023 460668927  43003905  20.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       417665024 460668927  43003904  20.5G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 7.2 GiB, 7742685184 bytes, 15122432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x28e78044

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 15122431 15120384  7.2G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)    

Disk /dev/mapper/ddf1_4d415256454c4c20ab112391ab112391c54a221253fe0001: 223.5 GiB, 239973523456 bytes, 468698288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I can't figure out what the `/dev/mapper/ddf1_4d415256454c4c20ab112391ab112391c54a221253fe0001` is, why Linux Mint installer can only see this device and not `/dev/sda`. Moreover, why GParted is not able to format the partition in `ext4` format?

Comment: What kind of disk definition did you use for Windows?  e.g. MBR, GPT, RAID, encryption, ...